# YII: Call to a member function offset() on a non-object

Tags: php, yii2

I am very new to php and yii2, i am trying to read all data records by active record
The code below give error **Call to a member function offset() on a non-object**

```
$cmylist = ClassInfo::find()->all();
$pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => count($cmylist)]);
$models = $cmylist->offset($pages->offset)->limit($pages->limit)->all();
```

Seems cmylist is a array and i can not call offset and count on it
This is really made me crazy, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Of course, if You call all() it's create final result. Call `->offset()` before `->all()`

just see
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-pagination.html

Answer (score 0):

Calling all() returns array of result models, You need to adjust Your code this way:

```
$cmylist = ClassInfo::find(); //activeQuery instance
$pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $cmylist->count()]);
$models = $cmylist->offset($pages->offset)->limit($pages->limit)->all();
```